# Create new dataframe which summarizes the number of occurences for different numeric ranges of some other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, discrete

I have dataframe `df` as shown in the first photo. Green rows are the ones which have column Condition1 as 'Yes'. Yellow rows are the ones which have BOTH columns `Condition1` and `Condition2` as 'Yes'.

**Question:**
See **second photo** which shows desired output which is a new dataframe in which:

(1). Column 'Count_Condition1' contains the number of times green row occurs. The column 'Count_Condition_1&2' contains the number of times yellow rows occur.

(2). In addition to (1), I would like to split the column 'Vol' to different ranges (see second photo) and the counts be displayed accordingly.

For example, there are 3 instances when Condition1= 'Yes' and the data range for `Vol` is between 0.2 to 0.2999.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) for bining column `Vol` and for count match `Yes` values create helper columns, last aggregate boolean for count `True`s:

```
bins=[-np.inf, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, np.inf]

labels = [ f'{a} to {round(b-0.0001, 4)}'.replace('-inf to ', '<=').replace(' to inf', '') 
          for a, b in zip(bins, bins[1:])]
labels[-1] = '>=' + labels[-1]

s1 = df['Condition1'].eq('Yes')
s2 = df['Condition2'].eq('Yes')
g = pd.cut(df['Vol'], bins = bins, right = False, labels = labels)


df1 = (df.assign(Count_Condition1 = s1, Count_Condition_1_2 = s1 & s2)
         .groupby(g)[['Count_Condition1','Count_Condition_1_2']]
         .sum())
print (df1)
               Count_Condition1  Count_Condition_1_2
Vol                                                 
<=0.1999                      2                    1
0.2 to 0.2999                 3                    1
0.3 to 0.3999                 1                    1
0.4 to 0.4999                 1                    0
>=0.5                         2                    2
```